# HTML/CSS How do I mass edit URLs used on a web page to shorten them LOCALLY

Tags: html, css

Essentially I need to remove `/small` from multiple URLs on a web page to view the higher quality image of all shown images. The issue is there are over 300 images.

```
<img src="https://images.cdn.manheim.com/20200601173044-0caa4ff1-471f-4a93-ab3d-a387e912fe70/small.jpg" width="60" height="45">
```

I'm not sure if this is possible with my almost non-existent experience with HTML. I've tried CSS live editors, overwrites with inspect element to change the element style with no success other than resizing the images with the same low resolution.

Any point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, here is a code snippet of your current code, with `width` and `height` attributes removed so that you can see the difference between the sizes.

When you run the snippet below, it will display the small version of your image:

```html
<img src="https://images.cdn.manheim.com/20200601173044-0caa4ff1-471f-4a93-ab3d-a387e912fe70/small.jpg">
```

The second snippet has exactly the same HTML, but with some javascript added to it. The javascript goes through all images and removes the string `/small` from their `src` attribute.

To do this, the `replace()` function is used. Its first parameter is the string to be replaced, which in your case is the `"/small"`, and the second parameter is the string which should replace this, which in your case is `""` (empty string) because you want to delete that part of the string and not write any new text into it.

As you can see, the large version of the image is now displayed:

```js
var allImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++) {
  var newSource = allImages[i].src.replace("/small", "");
  allImages[i].src = newSource;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.cdn.manheim.com/20200601173044-0caa4ff1-471f-4a93-ab3d-a387e912fe70/small.jpg">
```

If there are several, or even 300 images on a page, this javascript will go through all of them and change their `src` attributes accordingly.